# Solaris noexec_user_stack Issues

Tags: heap-memory, solaris, buffer-overflow

Would enabling *noexec_user_stack* parameter in Solaris prevent some geniune programs from running? 
Has anyone tested this setting please?

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of GCC in 32bit mode can create code that relies on executable stacks ([Nested Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) / [Trampolines](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Trampolines.html)). 
See also [Implementation of nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179521/implementation-of-nested-functions) and [Example of executable stack in Linux (i386 architecture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564298/example-of-executable-stack-in-linux-i386-architecture) on StackOverflow.

This is known to be "broken" by `noexec_user_stack` in Solaris (just as noexec stacks do in Linux), and yes it's one way to test the effectiveness of the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses just in time (JIT) compiling which means it will generate code on the fly and run it in writable/data sections. This is most likely implemented in the heap with `mprotect()` on pages or in an anonymous mapping via `mmap()`, both of which will probably have `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC` at a low level. However, I don't believe Java does JIT on the actual stack, so you may *not* have issues with Java on Solaris with this limited memory protection, though you would have problems on Linux systems with PaX in Linux (fixable with `paxctl`or problems with the relatively newer W^X on OpenBSD. When it comes to Solaris, I suspect you probably won't since Oracle owns both Sun and Java and strongly pushes their use together.

So, if Java immediately and consistently crashes, no-exec stack is likely why. But you should be OK.

**EDIT**: I said "relatively new" not to imply W^X is "new" but to point out that it came along after PaX was "a thing." W^X is just a small subset of the features of PaX that came along later